# my app is crashing check the logcat error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, firebase-authentication, build.gradle, logcat

**Logcat**
E  Access denied finding property "ro.odm.prev.product.name"
2023-08-02 19:07:57.330 22821-22821 Perf                    com.example.chit_chat                I  Connecting to perf service.
2023-08-02 19:07:57.339 22821-22821 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.chit_chat                D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-08-02 19:07:57.340 22821-22821 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.chit_chat                D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-08-02 19:07:57.356 22821-22821 AndroidRuntime          com.example.chit_chat                D  Shutting down VM
2023-08-02 19:07:57.358 22821-22821 AndroidRuntime          com.example.chit_chat                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chit_chat, PID: 22821
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/appcheck/interop/InternalAppCheckTokenProvider;
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar.getComponents(DatabaseRegistrar.java:38)
at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar(ComponentMonitor.java:28)
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:117)
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:99)
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:46)
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:387)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(FirebaseApp.java:439)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:296)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:264)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:249)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:66)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:58)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7802)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7343)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:293)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2145)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8243)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.appcheck.interop.InternalAppCheckTokenProvider" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.chit_chat/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~NLpPi_RVrliNO1jQQvzdpw==/com.example.chit_chat-E3mHgMsKZBsjbahTHDiu2g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~NLpPi_RVrliNO1jQQvzdpw==/com.example.chit_chat-E3mHgMsKZBsjbahTHDiu2g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /odm/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar.getComponents(DatabaseRegistrar.java:38) 
at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar(ComponentMonitor.java:28) 
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:117) 
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:99) 
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:46) 
at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:387) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(FirebaseApp.java:439) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:296) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:264) 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:249) 
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:66) 
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388) 
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358) 
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:58) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7802) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7343) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:293) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2145) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8243) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006) 
2023-08-02 19:07:57.368 22821-22821 Process                 com.example.chit_chat                I  Sending signal. PID: 22821 SIG: 9
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3DTs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilt1k.png)

i try to run my app
it is a chat application when i run this app, app is crash without any error please read the logcat